# UITableView content size and row height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView added as a subview with a size of 320px width and 44px height with 1 row, and actually is a scrollable table view that means the cell + the space is more than 44px, does anybody know the space between the table view border and the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to change the space between the both? in IB there is a functionality to change the height of the table,header,footer.you can change it from there.